# how to format 12 hours time in Raspi lcd with I2C

Tags: python, i2c, lcd

[image]
I would like to change my lcd 24 hours time format to 12 hours

```
import lcddriver
import time
import datetime

display = lcddriver.lcd()

try:
    print("Writing to display")
    display.lcd_display_string("Time", 1) 
    while True:
        display.lcd_display_string(str(datetime.datetime.now().time()), 2)            

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Cleaning up!")
    display.lcd_clear()
```

Comment: Please provide a bit of context to your Python code.

Comment: Did you read `man locale`? Does it help?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `datetime` module in python like this:

```
import lcddriver
import time
import datetime

display = lcddriver.lcd()

try:
    print("Writing to display")
    display.lcd_display_string("Time", 1) 
    while True:
        datestr = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
        display.lcd_display_string(datestr, 2)            

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Cleaning up!")
    display.lcd_clear()
```

For example, if current time is **15:40:50** then `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")` outputs **03:40:50 PM**

Hope it helps you!

Comment: And why we have locale then?